# Does Convert.ChangeType() creates a copy of the object or returns reference of the original object?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I have this data which can be very big in size, this could be an xmlstring, dataset, datatable, datarowcollection. This data will be passed to generic method together with its type.

```
void GenericMethod(object data, Type t)
{
   var d = Convert.ChangeType(data, t);  
   //some tasks to do 
}
```

Question: if data is 1GB, will ChangeType creates another object with 1GB also?
I just want to be sure, because of the memory usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType` calls the instance's `IConvertible` implementation, which is free to do whatever it wants to.

If the passed object does not implement `IConvertible`, an exception is thrown.

Comment: Are you sure?  The sample IConvertable implementation on MSDN calls Convert.ChangeType.  That in turn calls IConvertable for the type being changed to?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx

Comment: @EricJ.: It calls `ChangeType()` on a `double`, not on itself.

Comment: does this mean, no copy has been created if no exception is thrown?

Comment: @jerjer - it means anything could have happened - you'd need to know the concrete types involved, and whether they even document any copying/space guarantees.

Comment: thanks, so this means that if the data type is dataset, Convert.ChangeType(data, dataset) will not create a copy, am i correct?

Comment: @jerjer:`DataSet` doesn't implement `IConvertible`, so it will just throw an exception.